# How to check if link exists to certain breed?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to implement an if statement that checks if a turtle has a link to a specific breed, but I cannot find any documentation anywhere on how to do this. Is it possible?

Tried using 'links with breed' but gives an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `link-neighbors` and `with` primitives.

Here's a simple made-up example but if you post your code, I can give a more specific answer:

```
breed [stores store]
breed [customers customer]

to setup
   clear-all

   create-stores 10
   create-customers 10 [ create-links-with one-of stores ]

   reset-ticks
end

to check-busy-stores
   ask stores [
     ifelse any? link-neighbors with [breed = customers] [
        set color green
     ][
        set color red
     ]
   ]
end
```

The following pages have further information about `link-neighbors` and `with` primitives:

- https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/bind/primitive/link-neighbors.html
- https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/bind/primitive/with.html